# Which new reputation does a meta site report?

Tags: support, profile-page, user-accounts

Looking at [my account on meta.english.stackexchange.com](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/users/252/kiamlaluno), I noticed that the reputation tab reports an increase of 2220 on my reputation, but calculating the reputation I would get from up votes, and accepting answers, I would not even reach a total of 2220.

It's not even the new reputation I have on the main site, as I didn't get my reputation increased by 2220 since last time I have checked my user profile.

Which new reputation is reported in a meta site?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I noticed this on http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com, but I could not take a screenshot because once I counted the reputation I would  have on that meta, the "new reputation" badge vanished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at my account on a few metas, it seems to be my reputation on the main site since about March 6.

My guess is that, like on the main site, the figure is the reputation accrued since you last looked at that tab. Oddly, on the meta, the tab shows accrued meta reputation, but the tab title computes accrued main site reputation for the meta acquisition period.

If, like me, you never looked at your reputation tab on a meta site, the acquisition period began when the reputation tab was overhauled, with the removal of the envelope.

Comment: Let me see if I understood; the reputation tab on a meta site shows the change of reputation in the main site, since the last time I watched my user profile on the meta site.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Yes, that's it (except that this is specifically the number in the tab heading; the tab contents is the meta rep).